# How to keep the html table unchanged after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have created a web page containing two text boxes to get user inputs, and a button to add those values to an html table as a new row. I have used JavaScript to do this function. Here is my code:

**JavaScript code**

```
function addData(tableID)
{   
            var t = document.getElementById("timeslot").value;
            var m = document.getElementById("mon").value;
        
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
         
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createTextNode(t);
            element1.type = "label";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);
        
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createTextNode(m);
            element2.type = "label";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);
}
```

**HTML code**

```
    <input type='button' name='Add' value='Add' style='width:130px;padding:10px;' onclick="addData('timetable')">
```

This code functions correctly.
But when I refresh the page, the newly added rows are disappearing and my page becomes as it was, before I insert new rows. How do I avoid this and keep my table without changing the newly added fields?

Comment: Are you using any kind of server-side code?

Comment: JavaScript will not alter the original HTML, so if the page refreshes, you lose all changes made via JavaScript.  To "save" those changes without server-side code, you would need to use cookies or local storage, and that will still be somewhat temporary.

Comment: Thank u very much....I'll use cookies to function it..

Comment: Is there any way to use jquery to do this??

Comment: Why do you refresh the page?

Comment: I am doing this timetable as one page.If I navigate to another page and comes back those data disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it statically or dynamically each time the page reload.

Comment: Thank u..But I couldnot get it.Can u plzz exlain??

Comment: Where you store your page, in your machine? in a server?

Comment: Ok, you can edit the html in order to add the cells avoiding generating dynamically, or is you want add an onload= "addData('tablename');" to your body tag.